# How can I trigger a control event when a ListViewItem is selected?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5, styles

I have an image that I want to show only when a `ListViewItem` is selected. The code I have isn't working, but I think it illustrates what I want to accomplish.

```
<GridViewColumn>
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Image Height="20">
            <Image.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                  <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource=
                           {
                              RelativeSource 
                              Mode=FindAncestor, 
                              AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}
                           }, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Russound.Windows;component/Resources/2leftarrow-64.png" />
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Selected" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
            </Image.Style>
         </Image>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with binding issues, I generally search through the Output window to find any binding errors. They all start with System.Windows.DataError. So, are there any errors in the Output window?

Comment: Well, I will say that I did not know about the DataError in the output window. Thank you, I fixed several other binding problems, HOWEVER, this specific issue is not throwing an error.

Comment: Try this, have two DataTriggers, one when IsSelected is true and the other one for false. And also remove that Setter. What I'm suspecting is that dependency property resolution is always picking that setter value for it has a higher precedence than style triggers. I have faced this problem before, but I don't really remember the exact situation.

Comment: For more information, check MSDN @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the default Visibility to Hidden instead of Collapsed.

Apparently, if you use Collapsed, the element is removed from the visual tree and the RelativeSource no longer works.

Comment: Changing to Hidden is a No Go Jalfp

Comment: I built a sample application that works using your code with Hidden instead of Collapsed. Maybe I didn't understand what you want to accomplish...